# winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException when using setStatus() in Android

Tags: android, jtwitter

I just created a simple interface with two EditText fields to give Username and Password to log in with Twitter account. I have correctly added jtwitter.jar file in to my project. Then when I try to run the following code;

```
    twitter = new Twitter(givenUsername, givenPassword);

try {
    twitter.setStatus("hello");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "login success...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception caz of setStatus :" + e);
}
```

it gives me an error;

> Updater.run exception: winterwell.jtwitter.TwitterException: 401 Unauthorized http://twitter.com/statuses/friends_timeline.json

I have given Internet permission in my Manifest file.

Please help me to implement my own Android Twitter app.

Answer (score 0):

The 401 error is from Twitter, and it means your app isn't authenticating with them.

I see you're using: `twitter = new Twitter(givenUsername, givenPassword);`
This isn't supported by Twitter! (see the javadoc).

NB: It is supported by some Twitter-like services which support the Twitter API (e.g. Wordpress). But Twitter themselves stopped supporting it quite a while ago.

To authenticate with Twitter, you'll need to use oauth. Have a look at `OAuthSignpostClient`.
There's also help on the [JTwitter webpage](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php)